# Oracle managed data access TNS no listener

Tags: oracle, odp.net

Below is my config file

```
<configuration>
  <configSections>
<section name="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client"   
type="OracleInternal.Common.ODPMSectionHandler, Oracle.ManagedDataAccess" />
</configSections>
<startup>
<supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
</startup>
<connectionStrings>
<add name="DBNAME" connectionString="User Id=USERNAME; Password=PASSWORD; Data      Source=DEV01" providerName="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client"/>
 </connectionStrings>
 <oracle.manageddataaccess.client>
 <version number="4.121.1.0">
  <dataSources>
    <dataSource alias="DEV01" descriptor="(DESCRIPTION = (ADDRESS_LIST = (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = HOST)(PORT = PORT))(CONNECT_DATA = (SERVER = DEDICATED)(SERVICE_NAME = dev01.local.junk)))" />
  </dataSources>
</version>
</oracle.manageddataaccess.client>
</configuration>
```

I also have the descriptor in my tnsnames.ora. I am able to tnsping dev01 and it makes the connection just fine. I can also put the descriptor directly in for the connection string hard coded for data soruce and it connects to the DB just fine. There is something wrong and the tnsnames doesnt seem to work otherwise. I feel its something in my config file but cannot seem to figure it out.

EDIT:

Its read from code by

```
if (_configReader != null)
        {
            _connectionString =
                     _configReader.ConnectionStringsSection.ConnectionStrings["DBNAME"].ConnectionString;

        }

OracleConnection connection = new OracleConnection(_connectionString);
            connection.Open();
```

which returns the connectionstring from above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it looks like in your descriptor you don't close all of your parentheses. I don't think you need the address_list in there either... try using

```
(DESCRIPTION = (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = HOST)(PORT = PORT))(CONNECT_DATA = (SERVER = DEDICATED)(SERVICE_NAME = dev01.local.junk)))
```

EDIT:

Finally found the problem. First, your section name for the manageddataaccess HAS to be lowercase, or else it won't match.

Second, I'm not sure what your _configReader is, but I simply used a System.Configuration.Configuration object and it worked, like this:

```
// Get the application configuration file.
                System.Configuration.Configuration config =
                        ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(
                        ConfigurationUserLevel.None);

                if (config != null)
                {
                    ConnectionStringSettings settings  = new ConnectionStringSettings("DEV01", config.ConnectionStrings.ConnectionStrings["DBNAME"].ToString());
                    OracleConnection connection = new OracleConnection(settings.ConnectionString);
                    connection.Open();
                }
```

The only changes I made to your config file were change the section name value to lowercase.

Comment: good pick up on the parentheses but didnt fix it still no listener. Thanks

Comment: hmmm. Everything else looks OK to me, you could try either changing your version number value to '*' or alternatively, referencing your TNSNames using 

<settings>
    <setting name="TNS_ADMIN" value="C:\tnsfiles"/>
</settings>

just to verify that it is something in the config file.

Comment: Ya i did both those suggestions. You think its something in my config file now?

Comment: Also can you post some code that shows how you're accessing this from your project?

Comment: Edited to show solution, turns out it was in the config file, it's case sensitive, and so couldn't find a match from section name="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client" to the element oracle.manageddataaccess.client

Comment: I ended up getting it working using TNS_ADMIN and my tnsnames.ora file because of other peoples preferences to that way but it seems you were correct. Thanks